# Reformat Excel List into Tagged Search

Tags: database, excel, list, tags

I've got an Excel list of over 300 website addresses that I use for ideas when designing web sites/apps.

In one column I have all the URLs, in the second column I list their "tags" for what I like about them. For instance, "background color", "heading font", "color scheme", "contact form", etc. I have around 25 different tags at this point, and many URLs have multiple tags.

It's difficult to sort through this list when I'm searching for something in particular. And creating an individual cell for each tag along the same row for each URL seems highly inefficient.

Is there some kind of web application I can use that will enable me to assign custom tags to each URL and then search by tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By formatting the data in two columns and repeating the URL, this data would be structured in such a way that a PivotTable or AutoFilter would make it easy to search by tag.

```
SITE | TAG 
URL1 | Tag1 
URL1 | Tag2
URL1 | Tag3
URL2 | Tag1
URL2 | Tag3
URL3 | Tag1
```

If a tag doesn't apply to that site, there will be no record. Once the data is formatted this way, highlight the range or a cell in the range and then from "Sort & Filter" select "Filter."  This works best if you're only searching one tag at a time. If you want multiple tags, use a PivotTable instead of AutoFilter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a web application that does that.
But if your tags are listed as a string, then you can use the search() function (e.g. in the third column) to check whether a specific tag is present in that string, then sort on that search result.

Comment: Thanks, Rob. Each cell is indeed a string of comma-separated tags. I'll have to look into the Excel search() function, which I haven't used before. If you can refer me to any documentation, examples or code, that would be great. Also, however, managing these tags (adding/deleting/editing) will still be a bit unwieldy. Looking for something simpler (like labels in gmail).

Comment: The Office web site provides more info on search and find:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/search-searchb-functions-HP010342873.aspx
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx?CTT=1